# Monitor GPIO activity to debug possibly broken script

Tags: gpio, case, gpiozero

I recently picked up a b3+ and a nespi+ case. The case comes with a power and reset button and provides a [script for the safe shutdown](https://github.com/RetroFlag/retroflag-picase/blob/master/SafeShutdown.py) and for the most part has been driving me insane.

I've fixed the script so that the reset works when run from terminal as the killall command would stop further processing, so this seems to work fine.

The shutdown commands on the other hand are giving me some issues. I know the button is functioning as from a hardware level it does trigger the power on, however when I modify the script for the `when_pressed` and `when_released` actions of the buttons to print out a debug message, it will not fire.

I've tried to look up GPIO monitoring tools, but most of these seem to run on s remote machine or run through the GUI. However I"m currently toying with retropi so I don't have access to the GUI and the only GPIO monitor I found that runs via terminal  does not seem to work with the b3+ hardware.

While I'm competent at using linux and am a programmer this is my first time playing with a Raspberry pi and Python so I'm somewhat lacking tools to debug any possible hardware issues. My first thought was that the pins might have been wrong for power but that was just a guess. I found a script that apparently would let me debug GPIO but it also said to not do this if anything controlling power was connected as this would change how the pin worked, so I avoided doing that without knowing too much about how the GPIO controls worked.

Comment: Seeing that the script uses GPIO2/3: are you sure i2c is disabled?

Comment: Had to google I2C but I don't know. I've done nothing but install retropi that script and some python libs and scripts to try to debug.

Comment: There should not be an entry 'dtparam=i2c' or similar in /boot/config.txt. Alternatively use 'sudo raspi-config' and disable it explicitly.

Comment: It's best not to use those pins for your buttons. The pullup resisters  are stronger, which can cause some circuits to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a GUI solution (remote or local) you can use [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html).

For a non-GUI terminal based monitor you can use [monitor.py](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py).

Both require the pigpio daemon to be running (`sudo pigpiod`).

pigpio is installed on full Raspbian.  On Raspbian Lite it may be installed with

`sudo apt-get install pigpio python-pigpio python3-pigpio`

Both mentioned monitoring options are purely passive.  They do not affect the GPIO in any way.

Comment: Marking as correct answer as this did let me confirm the pin numbers as correct